# Power BI/Power Query: I want to make a relationship with a dimensional table where the dimensions are in rows but the fact table is in columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm sorry if this is asked before but I couldn't find it at the moment.

I have 2 tables, they are sorted as follows:

Fact table:

Description; Amount; Dimension 1 code; Dimension 2 code; Dimension 3 code; Dimension 4 code

Dimension table:

Dimension type; Dimension type description; Dimension code; Dimension code Description

So how the dimension table is essentially sorted is that under the Dimension column you have numbers 1 - 4 repeated several times. Then there is a code belonging to the dimension type (1-4) and a description.

How do I make the relationship between my fact table and my dimensional table, since the dimension code in my fact table is spread out over 4 columns and in the dimension table the code is under one column?

Thanks in advance.

Here an example of my dimension dataset (it is in Dutch):

[image: Example dimension dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make 4 copies of the "dimension" table in Power Query, each one filtered to a single dimension.  Then bring that into your Power BI data model as 4 separate dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed what I ended up doing and it worked.